# Why is it illegal to use both prefix and postfix at the same time?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

*Why* is the following code illegal?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        --i++;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

It gives me the following error on the `--i++`:

> `The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer`

I know that this code has no practical use; I'm merely curious why it is not allowed.  I don't care that it can be fixed by removing that line with no other effects.  As this is tagged with [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), please include evidence from the language specification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the C# specification "7.6.9 Postfix increment and decrement operators":

> The operand of a postfix increment or decrement operation must be **an expression classified as a variable, a property access, or an indexer access**. The result of the operation is **a value** of the same type as the operand.

I think this answers your question.

It's also the reason you can't do `i++++`, nor with parentheses: `(i++)++` gives the same compilation error as well.

Answer (score 13):

`--` returns a value, not a variable but the operator at `++` expects it to be a variable, that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The `--` and `++` operators don't just return values, they *change the variable* that they operate on. No matter which order you try to evaluate `--i++`, the first operator returns a *value*, which the second operator will not be able to assign its return value back to.